# Во второй секции под картинками с браузерами добавляется нижний отступ ,как его убрать?

Tags: вёрстка

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(../img/main_bg.png) no-repeat center;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-color: #474642;
  background-size: cover;
}
header .wrap {
  width: 100vw;
}
header .wrap nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 15vh;
  line-height: 15vh;
}
header .wrap nav .logo {
  padding-left: 376px;
  padding-right: 220px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
header .wrap nav .logo span {
  font-size: 34px;
  letter-spacing: -1.36px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway;
}
header .wrap nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
header .wrap nav ul li {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
header .wrap nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}
header .wrap nav ul a:hover {
  color: #b5a28c;
}
header .wrap nav ul i {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}
header .wrap nav ul i:hover {
  color: #b5a28c;
}
header .wrap nav ul .font_icon {
  padding-left: 63px;
}
header .wrap .main {
  padding-top: 250px;
}
header .wrap .main h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Raleway;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-left: 732px;
}
header .wrap .main h1 {
  font-size: 52px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 666px;
}
header .wrap .main p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 680px;
  padding-bottom: 52px;
}
header .wrap .main a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 21px 37px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Raleway;
  background: #998675;
  margin-left: 876px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #736357;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #736357;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
section.content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
section.content .carts {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
section.content .carts .cart {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
section.content .carts .cart img {
  padding-bottom: 29px;
}
section.content .carts .cart h4 {
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
section.content .carts .cart p {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
section.content .carts .cart span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #f1eee9;
}
section.content .carts .cart:nth-child(2) h4 {
  color: #c7b299;
}
section.content .carts .cart:nth-child(2) p {
  padding-bottom: 33px;
}
section.content .carts .cart:nth-child(2) span {
  background-color: #c7b299;
}
section.content .ideas {
  padding-top: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}
section.content .ideas h2 {
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
section.content .ideas p {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
section.content .browsers {
  position: relative;
  height: 490px;
}
section.content .browsers .browser {
  position: absolute;
}
section.content .browsers .center {
  z-index: 99;
  left: 30%;
}
section.content .browsers .left {
  z-index: 1;
  left: 17%;
  top: 16.7%;
}
section.content .browsers .right {
  z-index: 0;
  right: 16%;
  top: 16.7%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Waxom</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
     <span>Waxom</span>
    </div>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Shortcodes</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     <li class="font_icon"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i></li>
     <li><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <div class="main">
    <h2>Unique and Modern Design</h2>
    <h1>Portfolio PSD Template</h1>
    <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imper- <br>  diet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    <a href="#">Get Started</a>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </header>
 <section class="content">
  <div class="wrap_2">
   <div class="carts">
    <div class="cart">
     <img src="img/sec_icon_1.png" alt="">
     <h4>Web & App Design</h4>
     <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis <br>eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet <br>doming id quod mazim.</p>
     <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
     <img src="img/sec_icon_2.png" alt="">
     <h4>Development</h4>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing <br>elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod <br>tincidunt ut laoreet.</p>
     <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
     <img src="img/sec_icon_3.png" alt="">
     <h4>Customization</h4>
     <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis <br>eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet <br>doming id quod mazim.</p>
     <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
     <img src="img/sec_icon_4.png" alt="">
     <h4>Marketing</h4>
     <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis <br>eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet <br>doming id quod mazim.</p>
     <span></span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ideas">
    <h2>Waxom is Realization of your Ideas.</h2>
    <p>Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam <br>processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="browsers">
   <div class=" browser left">
    <img src="img/browser-left.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class=" browser center">
    <img src="img/browser-center.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class=" browser right">
    <img src="img/browser-right.png" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: img{display: block}

Comment: Какому блоку это добавить ?

Comment: я же написал  `img{ display: block}`